# Issues with assigning values to variable in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve the project euler problem 4 - Largest palindrome product.
I'm stuck with these two bugs and I'm not sure why its happening.

Hi, basically there are two issues with the code which I have no idea why.

1 ) Defining `inv = 0` outside the while loop and inside, somehow when I define 
    it outside my `inv` value is not zero even when defined `inv = 0`. Defining it 
    inside the loop solves the issue. Why does this happen?

2)  The `if` statement (`if count == inv`) does not break because it seem to not 
    to able to know when both of the variable are equal

Is there something wrong with the way I define the variables ?

```
## define the variables
triple = 999
h_triple = triple**2
print ("\n")
print ("Highest Possible Value is :",h_triple)
print ("\n")
ori = h_triple
#inv = 0 ISSUE 1: does not work
count = h_triple

## run the calculation
while True :
  ori = count 
  inv = 0 
  # ISSUE 1 : this works properly
  # inv default value not zero if put outside loop
  while ori > 0:
    inv = inv*10 + ori % 10
    ori = ori // 10  
  count -= 1
  print ("inverse :",inv)
  #print ("original :",ori)
  print ("count   :",count)
  # ISSUE 2 : count == inv, does not work
  if count == inv :
    print ("\n")
    print ("Answer is :",count)
    break
```

Comment: When you have simple problems like this. use `print` like `print(count, inv)` in your while loop to track them.

Comment: I think a problem is that you decrease `count` but also you change `inv` in the nested while and `count` and `inv` are not meeting. If you will use `if count <= inv` then this if-section will be reached.

Comment: btw, you can use "pdb" or visual debuggers to fight the bugs

Comment: Hi Paul, if is use [(if count <= inv)] it will break early since the maths reverse the original number thus breaks early. To solve the equation i would it need to meet the exact value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) When you set `i = 0` outside the loop, then this operation is not repeated any more. And that means that at the beginning of each loop iteration `i` has the same value it had at the end of the previous loop iteration. If you require it to be set to `0` at the beginning of each loop iteration, you have to place this operation inside, not before loop.

2) Both `count` and `inv` are `int` type in your code, so the only possibility that "if block" does not execute is they never meet. Check your algorithm.

Comment: 1) Understood, that explains it.
2) I did check, the values meet at 906609. When i manually change the inv variable into 906609, it meets.

These are the results : 
inverse : 110609
count   : 906010
inverse : 10609
count   : 906009
inverse : 900609
count   : 906008

But somehow it doesn't break.

Comment: 2) I didn't inspect your algorithm thoroughly, but I ran it for some couple of minutes and the values didn't meet. The best case was the difference equal to 1.

Comment: Yes, you were right. The difference was equal to 1. The if statement was finding the variable count after incremental when it was suppose to find the value before incremented. Thank you, Stanowczo.